# Wordpress two background images in page layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, background

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to have a gradient image on the top of my page, and then another one that is on the bottom.  I'm using a 1px wide image and using the repeat-x css property, so It can't just be one image.  The gradients extend farther into the page than either the header or footer, so using backgrounds only for those isn't really an option.  Is there a way to create a new div or have multiple backgrounds for a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can apply [multiple background images with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) but it's not recommended as browser support is sketchy. Instead use a container (such as a `div`) for each background image. Alternatively use `img` tags and absolutely position them with CSS with a [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Hope that helps

Comment: Interesting.  Is the browser support sketchy with both methods or only the first?  i forgot about absolute positioning.

Comment: Browser support is only sketchy for the first CSS3 option, as it's a relatively new thing that older browsers won't support.